# Index MVC c# Diseño

Tags: html, c#, css, mvc

tengo este CSS en MVC:

```
body {
}

/* The navbar container */
.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
}

    /* Navbar links */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}   

       /* Links - change color on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 165px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 12px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 90px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: darkred;
}

div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
}

/* PAra el celu */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .col-25, .col-75, input[type=submit] {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
```

Y este es la vista **Index** donde lo aplico:

```
@model IEnumerable<Certificaciones.Models.Certificados>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Inicio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Estilos/inicio.css">
</head>
<body>

    <center>
        <div class="topnav" style="width: 350px">
            <a title="Providus S.A" href="http://www.providus.com.ar"><img src="~/Images/00.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 350px">
            <form method="post" action="@Url.Action("Pdf", "Home")">
                <label for="solicitud">Solicitud: </label>
                <input type="text" id="solicitud" minlength="5" maxlength="7" name="solicitud" placeholder="Solicitud" required="required">
                <input type="submit" value="Buscar" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </center>

    <p>@ViewData["Mensaje"]</p>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Pero, se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe como lo soluciono? Gracias.

Comment: Click derecho, inspeccionar elemento... Revisar cada elemento...

Comment: solucionar que?, cual es el problema?

Comment: El problema es que se ven esos tabs nombre de la aplicacion, inicio, etc @Shassain

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, lo hice eliminando carpetas que se crearon automáticamente con el proecto :) @fredyfx

Comment: Me late que tienes código no modificado  en tu `_layout.cshtml`, por otro lado, toma https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY te ayudará a entender el panorama de ASP .net MVC 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución fue:

```
Borrar la carpeta Shared con el archivo layout y el archivo Viewstart
```

Comment: Creo que mejor lleva un curso del tema, toma https://Microsoft.com/Learn ahi hay cursos muy buenos :D